# Converting single row into multiple rows based on values in columns

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I have a table where each record represents a person and there are many columns used to indicate what events they attended:

```
CREATE TABLE EventAttendees
(
    Person VARCHAR(100),
    [Event A] VARCHAR(1),
    [Event B] VARCHAR(1),
    [Event C] VARCHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO EventAttendees
SELECT 'John Smith','x',NULL,NULL
UNION
SELECT 'Jane Doe',NULL,'x','x'
UNION
SELECT 'Phil White','x',NULL,'x'
UNION
SELECT 'Sarah Jenkins','x','x','x'
```

Which looks like this for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Event Attendees

/---------------|---------|---------|---------\
| Person        | Event A | Event B | Event C |
|---------------|---------|---------|---------|
| John Smith    |    x    |   NULL  |   NULL  |
| Jane Doe      |   NULL  |    x    |    x    |
| Phil White    |    x    |   NULL  |    x    |
| Sarah Jenkins |    x    |    x    |    x    |
\---------------|---------|---------|---------/
```

I want to generate a list of who attended which events, so my desired output is:

```
/---------------|---------|
| Person        | Event   |
|---------------|---------|
| John Smith    | Event A |
| Jane Doe      | Event B |
| Jane Doe      | Event C |
| Phil White    | Event A |
| Phil White    | Event C |
| Sarah Jenkins | Event A |
| Sarah Jenkins | Event B |
| Sarah Jenkins | Event C |
\---------------|---------/
```

In reality I have many more than 3 events, but the above is for ease of explanation (This is **not** a homework question btw). As the Events might change in the future and I have no control over the data I am being passed, I really need a dynamic solution which can handle any number of possible event columns.

I'm assuming I can do something with `UNPIVOT`, but I just can't figure it out, or find a good example on SO or elsewhere to work from - can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution I was thinking of, but yes, it does require dynamic SQL to get the relevant column names to feed into the `UNPIVOT`:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 
    'select Person, EventName
    from EventAttendees
    unpivot
    (
        Attended for EventName in (' + (select
                                        stuff((
                                            select ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[name])
                                            from sys.columns c
                                            join sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id
                                            where o.[name] = 'EventAttendees'
                                            and c.column_id > 1
                                            order by c.[name]
                                            for xml path('')
                                        ),1,1,'') as colList) + ')
    ) unpiv
    where unpiv.Attended = ''x''
    order by Person, EventName'

exec (@sql)
```

In this example, I am making the assumption that the Event columns are from the second column in the table onwards, but obviously I could use some different logic within the subquery to identify the relevant columns if necessary.

On my example data, this gives the desired result:

```
/---------------------------\
| Person        | EventName |
|---------------|-----------|
| Jane Doe      | Event B   |
| Jane Doe      | Event C   |
| John Smith    | Event A   |
| Phil White    | Event A   |
| Phil White    | Event C   |
| Sarah Jenkins | Event A   |
| Sarah Jenkins | Event B   |
| Sarah Jenkins | Event C   |
\---------------------------/
```

I think I prefer this to using a cursor, although I haven't actually confirmed what performance difference (if any) there is between the two dynamic approaches.

Thanks for everyone's help and suggestions on this question though, greatly appreciated as always!

Comment: One potential downside to calling `EXEC` with a string (arbitrary SQL) is that the caller of the code needs permissions to execute the arbitrary query. If you create a `STORED PROCEDURE` called `spGetAttendees` and grant a service user permissions to `EXEC spGetAttendees`, it won't work unless the service user is also granted permissions to `SELECT` from `EventAttendees`. I agree that this is the best solution, given the need to work on an arbitrary number of event name columns. My point is the more general one that dynamic queries require more permissions than compiled (constant) SQL queries.

Answer (score 3):

I do this using `outer apply`:

```
select ea.person, v.EventName
from EventAttendees ea outer apply
     (values ('Event A', [Event A]),
             ('Event B', [Event B]),
             ('Event C', [Event C])
     ) v(EventName, EventFlag)
where v.EventFlag = 'x'
```

Comment: As per [Yeou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8564491/yeou)'s answer, this would require a separate line within `values` for each Event - I have hundreds of events, so would rather not have to put together that large a statement if possible. Also, the Events might change in the future, so it really needs to be dynamic. I will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: @3N1GM4 . . . Your sample data has three events columns.  You have a problem with your application if you are routinely adding columns to a table.

Comment: I agree @GordonLinoff, but unfortunately that is outside of my control.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with unpivot as you said, you would just need to ensure you are telling it what event it is for, otherwise you just get an X:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpEventAttendees
(
    Person VARCHAR(100),
    [Event A] VARCHAR(1),
    [Event B] VARCHAR(1),
    [Event C] VARCHAR(1)
)
INSERT INTO #tmpEventAttendees
SELECT 'John Smith','x',NULL,NULL
UNION
SELECT 'Jane Doe',NULL,'x','x'
UNION
SELECT 'Phil White','x',NULL,'x'
UNION
SELECT 'Sarah Jenkins','x','x','x'

SELECT Person, [Event]
FROM
(
  SELECT    Person                                                                                  , 
            CASE WHEN [Event A] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Event A' END AS [Event A]                             , 
            CASE WHEN [Event B] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Event B' END AS [Event B]                             ,
            CASE WHEN [Event C] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Event C' END AS [Event C]
  FROM #tmpEventAttendees
) AS cp
UNPIVOT 
(
  [Event] FOR [Events] IN ([Event A], [Event B], [Event C])
) AS up;

DROP TABLE #tmpEventAttendees
```

Comment: As with the other answers, this requires me to re-write the query every time the Event columns change (adding new events, renaming events or removing events), so this is not going to help me.

Comment: Understood, that wasn't in your original question hence the code above. Will have a think.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT Person, CASE WHEN [Event A] = 'x' THEN 'Event A' END AS [Event] FROM EventAttendees
    UNION 
    SELECT Person, CASE WHEN [Event B] = 'x' THEN 'Event B' END AS [Event] FROM EventAttendees
    UNION 
    SELECT Person, CASE WHEN [Event C] = 'x' THEN 'Event C' END AS [Event] FROM EventAttendees
    ) AS EventAttendees
    WHERE Event is not null
    order by Person
```

For dynamic sql you can try something like this:

```
    DECLARE @name varchar(30)
    DECLARE @sql varchar(1000) = 'SELECT * FROM (';
    DECLARE NameCursor CURSOR
        FOR select name from sys.all_columns where object_id = (select object_id from sys.tables where name='EventAttendees') and name!='Person'
    OPEN NameCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM NameCursor INTO @name

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @sql += 'SELECT Person, CASE WHEN [' + @name+'] = ''x'' THEN ''' + @name +''' END AS [Event] FROM EventAttendees'   
        FETCH NEXT FROM NameCursor INTO @name

        IF(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @sql += ' UNION ';
        END

    END;
    CLOSE NameCursor;  
    DEALLOCATE NameCursor;
    SET @sql += ') AS EventAttendees
            WHERE Event is not null
            order by Person';

    execute (@sql);
```

Comment: But if I have 200 Event columns, I need 200 subqueries `UNION`ed together? I'm looking for a way to do this dynamically if possible.

Comment: are you generating new column for every new event?

Comment: I'm not personally, but the dataset I'm being passed does it that way, yes.

Comment: In that case you'll need to create dynamic sql

Comment: Really? There's no way to do this without dynamic SQL? I was sure I'd seen something similar before, but I can't find it now.

Comment: I can only think of dynamic sql, since there's no way to know how many columns are there.

Comment: @3N1GM4 I can only think of dynamic SQL - your issue is you have them marked as an X, not a meaningful piece of data. You can pull out the columns in the table, use a loop to get the column name for each column, then build the SQL to update the X to the 'event A' etc. I'd be interested to see how else it was done if you find another way.