# SQL create columns with sum of another column by unique items

Tags: sql, group-by, unique

I am a little bit new to SQL. So hope you can help me with this question as I didnt find answer yet.
I have joined tables from other sources and I need to create new columns based on unique values of one column with summ of another col. values.

For example, this is my table:

[image]

And this is what I need to get (Summ of `A` for each unique value in `B` added as a column):

[image]

For now I can do it manually like this:

```
SELECT 
    EM.[id]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN AM.[B]='ZA' THEN EM.[A] ELSE 0 END) "ZA_sum_A"
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN AM.[B]='ZB' THEN EM.[A] ELSE 0 END) "ZB_sum_A"
FROM [xxx].x.x  AS AM
  INNER JOIN [yyy].[y].[y] AS EM ON (AM.ELEMENT = EM.ELEMENT)
  WHERE ...
GROUP BY EM.[id]
```

But issue is that I can have hundreds of unique values in `B`.
So, question how to do it correctly..

Comment: Your code is correct.

Comment: I know, issue that now it's hardcoded each column manually. But it could be hundreds of types in B - a little bit unhealthy manually create each column..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the summed values of `EM.[A]` for each combination of `EM.[id]` and `AM.[B]`, you can do:

```
select
    em.[id],
    am.[B],
    sum(em.[A])
from [xxx].x.x as am
join [yyy].[y].[y] as em on am.ELEMENT = em.ELEMENT
where [...]
group by em.[id], am.[B]
```

If you then want to have the distinct values of `AM.[B]` appear as columns, so there is only one row for each distinct value of `EM.[id]`, you either need to know what the distinct values of `AM.[B]` are and use `PIVOT`.

If the exact values of `AM.[B]` are not known, or change often over time, you'll need to do something dynamic, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645342/5669294), but in the opposite direction.

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer if you found it useful.