# SQL pivoting out varying rows to columns

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, dynamic, pivot

I'm trying to create a dynamic SQL query that will pivot a varying number of rows to columns as needed. I'm querying a table to get a list of bin location and associated quantities based on an order number and it's line number.

I need to take this:

```
SalesOrder      |  Line | Bin    | Qty
000000000000892 |   1   | B12F01 |  2
000000000000892 |   1   | B12F02 |  2
000000000000892 |   1   | F01A01 |  2
```

and get this

```
SalesOrder      | Line  | Bin01  | QTY01 | Bin02  | QTY02 | Bin03  | QTY03
000000000000892 |  1    | B12F01 |  2    | B12F02 |  2    | F01A01 |  2
```

Sometimes it will be 1 BIN/QTY combination or upto 3 BIN/QTY combos.

I'm a little close with this:

```
declare @collist nvarchar(max)
SET @collist = stuff((select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Bin) 
            FROM SorDetailBin
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

declare @q nvarchar(max)
set @q = '
select * 
from (
    select SalesOrder, SalesOrderLine, Bin, StockQtyToShip
        from (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by Bin order by SalesOrder desc) as rn
        from SorDetailBin
    ) as x
) as source
pivot (
    max(StockQtyToShip)
    for Bin in (' + @collist + ')
) as pvt
'

exec (@q)
```

Which produces this

```
SalesOrder      | Line |B12F01 | B12F02  |F01A01    
000000000000892 | 1    | 2     |    2    | 2
```

I need to get the bin locations as field values and not column names

Any help or direction is appreciated.

Comment: Looks very similar to a question I asked, where I found a dynamic SQL solution detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645342/5669294).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @3N1GM4. Unfortunately, that solution is the opposite of what I need to accomplish. I need the bin and quantity row values from a common order number and order line to merge into a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Long research, trial and error, but I was able to work out a solution to this that gives exactly what I was looking for. Posting incase it can help others.

This table

```
CREATE TABLE #LabelBin (
  SalesOrder VARCHAR(20),
  Bin VARCHAR(20),
  Qty DECIMAL(18, 6)
)

INSERT INTO #LabelBin VALUES 
(000000000000892, 'A101', 1),
(000000000000892, 'B202', 2),
(000000000000892, 'C303', 3),
(000000000000892, 'D404', 4);
```

Looks like this

```
SalesOrder  |   Bin |   Qty
------------|-------|-------------
892         |A101   |   1.000000
892         |B202   |   2.000000
892         |C303   |   3.000000
892         |D404   |   4.000000
```

Here's the dynamic SQL query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = 
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(concat(col, '_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col ORDER BY Qty)))
         FROM #LabelBin
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Bin', Bin), ('Qty', cast(Qty as varchar))) v (col, value)
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
      ,1,1,'');

SET @query = 
  'SELECT SalesOrder, ' + @cols + '
   FROM
   (
     SELECT SalesOrder, concat(col, ''_'', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col ORDER BY Qty)) as col, value
     FROM #LabelBin
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(''Bin'', Bin), (''Qty'', cast(Qty as varchar))) v (col, value)
   ) s
   PIVOT
   (
     MAX(value)
     FOR col IN (' + @cols + ')
   ) piv';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

The results pivot like this
[Screenshot of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26mpb.png)

I hope this helps someone else.